# Rearrange integers of a given length to avoid nearby typos

Tags: gray-code

Inspired by [a post about car park identifiers](https://takes.jamesomalley.co.uk/p/an-important-parking-infrastructure), I started wondering if we could avoid two adjacent car parks having identifiers which could easily be mistaken for each other:

> What are the best arrangements of all the decimal numbers of a certain length are there that have the property that for each number, a single replacement or adjacent transposition does not occur in the list within X numbers.

(for example: 142 should not be near 172 (single replacement) nor 124 (adjacent transposition))

(I'm pretty happy with alternatives that have other criteria for typo-resistance)

##### Prior art

[Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) has the nice property that every number shares all-but-one (binary) digits; this feels like the opposite property of what I want.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what properties you want, but you may be looking for something closer to a [Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) (with error correcting properties) than a Gray code.

Comment: I'm not sure Hamming codes are right -- that seems to be about adding digits within a single identifier to ensure correct reception, whereas I'm hoping that within a finite space of numbers (which may all be used) to space out the nearly-colliding ones.